# How to malloc linked list node while reading file

Tags: c, file, file-io, linked-list, malloc

I've posted a question similar to this, but I was able to further narrow down the issue. I'm pretty sure I know what the problem is, but I've been stuck figuring out how to solve it.

```
//assuming typedef struct person person;

 struct person{
     char first_n[100];
     char last_n[100]; 
     char middle_n[100];
     struct person* next;
};


void open_file_and_read(char* file){
     FILE* fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
     if (fp != NULL){
         while (!feof(fp)){
               person* person = malloc(sizeof(person));
               person->next = NULL;
               while (fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s", person->first_n, person->last_n, person->middle_n) == 3){
                   add_to_contacts(person);
               }
         }
      }
}  

void open_write_file(char* file){
    FILE* filep = fopen(file, "w");
    person* copy;
    for (copy = front; copy != NULL; copy=copy->next){
            fprintf(filep, "%s %s %s\n", copy->last_n, copy->first_n, copy->middle_n);
    }
    fclose(filep);
```

}

```
void add_to_contacts(person* person){
    printf("last_name: %s", person->last_name);
    if (head == NULL){
        person->next = head;
        head = person;
    else{
        person->next = head;
        head = person;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
char* inputFilename = argv[1];
if (inputFilename == NULL){
    inputFilename = "myRolodex";
}
open_read_file(inputFilename);
char command;
while (command != 'Q' && command != 'q'){
    printf("STARTING TO READ COMMAND\n");
    command = read_command(inputFilename);
    evaluate_command(command);
}
open_write_file(inputFilename); 
clear_rolodex();
```

The printf prints out everything in the file as one node. Ex: file contains:
Bob Lee Steve
Mike Steven Noel  `first, last, middle`
James Nguyen Lee

the printf prints out `LeeStevenNguyen`. These should be separate.

I believe the problem has to do with malloc only being called once, when what I really need is for it to be called each time I scanf. However I can't move `person* person = malloc(sizeof(person));` under the `while...fscanf` loop because fscanf is dependent on having a `person` already created. So how do I go about mallocing each new person. A similar assignment is due in a couple of hours and I've spent the last 10 hours trying to get everything to work and I believe this is the big part.

Thank you

EDIT for more detail: I have a print statement in my `add_to_contacts` function that prints out the node->lasts_name. I also added a print statement before my sorting function(not posted) and it prints infinitely

Comment: Could you please include your `add_to_contacts` function?  Additionally, what exactly isn't working?  Is this crashing?  What tells you that there's something wrong?

Comment: 1) How about a compilable example that exhibits the problem, including the needed #include statements   2) It greatly helps us humans if the code is consistently indented. (suggest 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}')  3) the code will not cleanly compile for several reasons, including the main() parameter 'argc' is not used.  Suggest compiling with all warnings enabled, and fix the warnings. (for gcc, at a minimum, use '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')

Comment: there is a struct with tag name 'person'.  There is a typedef with the name 'person'  There is a pointer variable with type name 'person'.  There is a pointer variable named 'person'.   Just how obscure do you want the code to be?

Comment: the function: 'main()' calls 'open_read_file()' which is not defined in the posted code.  However, there is a function: 'open_file_and_read()', which is not called from anywhere in the posted code.    Strongly suggest posting the actual code as a compilable, item, the removes all the clutter, corrects the many problems listed here (and in the prior question).

Comment: regarding function: open_file_and_read()  1) never use 'feof()' as a loop control.   (suggest controlling the loop via the fscanf())    2) Only one malloc is being performed for a struct person, there should be a malloc() for each record read from the file.  3) always check the return value from malloc() to assure the operation was successful

Comment: per the code, there is a globally visible variable 'front'  and another 'head'; neither of which is in the posted code

Comment: the 'add_to_contacts()' function 1) is creating a circular linked list which means there is no easy way to determine when the end of the list has been reached. 2) always places the new contact as the first record 3) overwrites the prior contact with the new contact, so there is never more than one contact in the rolodex linked list  4) both code blocks of the 'if'/else' statements contain exactly the same code

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to resolve this.

The one that I think most directly matches what you want is:

```
               person* person = malloc(sizeof(person));
               person->next = NULL;
               while (fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s", person->first_n, person->last_n, person->middle_n) == 3){
                   add_to_contacts(person);
                   person = malloc(sizeof(person));
                   person->next = NULL;
               }
               free(person);
```

This assumes that `add_to_contacts` inserts the malloc'd
pointer into a data structure, so we need the next `fscanf` to put its
data in a different location.

Having done this, there will always be one `person*` allocated
at the end that is not actually ever passed to `add_to_contacts`, so we
can and should free that pointer when the loop exits.

A slight variation is

```
               person* person = malloc(sizeof(person));
               while (fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s", person->first_n, person->last_n, person->middle_n) == 3){
                   person->next = NULL;
                   add_to_contacts(person);
                   person = malloc(sizeof(person));
               }
               free(person);
```

(The idea there is that the only thing that needs `person->next = NULL;`
here is presumably `add_to_contacts(person)`, and by postponing
`person->next = NULL;` until the very last moment we don't have to call
it outside the loop as well as inside the loop.)

An alternative (quite different) approach is to
declare local variables, let `fscanf` write to them,
and copy them to a newly allocated `person` inside the loop.

A third approach is to make `person` a stack-allocated (not malloc'd) variable,
and make `add_to_contacts` make its own malloc'd copy of it in order
to insert the copy in the data structure.

But these last two options involve `fscanf` writing the data one place
and then having to copy it to another in order to put it in the larger structure. It seems you may want to avoid the copy.

Comment: I see that you malloc in the while loop and this would work, but what happens when you malloc, and then execute the while loop again and the while loop is false, wouldn't that mean there would be a person pointer pointing nowhere

Comment: Yes, that would be a memory leak (also present in the code before my proposed modifications, in the case where the input was empty). The leftover `person*` needs to be freed; I have added that to each version of the code.

Comment: I got my read_file to work, but now I think I have problems with my write_file which I can't seem to see why. I am provided a script for testing my files and my output file is 1 size less. I added my main and write_to

Comment: Lets' remember to always check the returned value from malloc() to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 0):

regarding this part of the question:

believe the problem has to do with malloc only being called once, when what I really need is for it to be called each time I scanf. However I can't move person* person = malloc(sizeof(person)); under the while...fscanf loop because fscanf is dependent on having a person already created

suggest fscanf() into local variables (remember to use length modifiers on the format parameters to avoid buffer overflow.

Then, within the loop, malloc, error check, copy variables, call function to insert malloc memory into linked list.